# Subscribe to an Action event with a different return type method

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, action

I have an event:

```
public event Action OnDamageTaken;
```

I'd like to subscribe to it in my behavior tree, but with a return type of TaskStatus, which when evaluated to TaskStatus.Success, would end current Task execution in the tree, like so:

```
Vegetation.OnDestroy += VegetationDestroyed;

public TaskStatus VegetationDestroyed()
{
    Owner.FindTask<JobChooser>().CurrentJob.OnJobCompleted();
    return TaskStatus.Success;
}
```

However, I get the following error:

[image: error]

Is something like this possible to do, and if not, why? I thought since the Action event passes no arguments, therefore, we can subscribe with a method that has any return type, as long as that method too requires no parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the method inside a lambda:

```
Vegetation.OnDestroy += () => VegetationDestroyed();
```

If you want to unsubscribe again from the event, you have to store the lambda inside a variable:

```
Action onDestroy = () => VegetationDestroyed();
Vegetation.OnDestroy += onDestroy;
Vegetation.OnDestroy -= onDestroy;
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AOYqbf

Comment: After the plant is destroyed, is there even a need to unsubscribe from the event? It will remove itself from all lists, and therefore I expect GC to clean it up, requiring no need to unsubscribe from the event.

Comment: I don't know your code, so I can't tell if it is necessary in your case. But if you have to unsubscribe, you  can read in my answer how you do it.

Comment: I see. After trying to implement the solution with storing the lambda, I get the following error:
Cannot convert source type 'lambda expression' to target type 'BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Tasks.Action'
I tried changing the return type from TaskStatus to bool, but the error message remains the same. What's wrong here? Updated the question with the screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Oh man, my bad. I set the Action type as the one from BehaviorDesigner because they're named the same...